# PyQt: how do I replace a widget using a button?

Tags: python, widget, pyqt

I'm trying to write a simple code which will change existing text widget to another one when user clicks a button.
So I have

```
title1=QtGui.QLabel('Hello')
title2=QtGui.QLabel('bye')
abutton=QtGui.QPushButton('Click me')
grid.addWidget(title1,1,5)
grid.addWidget(abutton,3,5)
```

and I have a function:

```
def myfunc(self):
        self.grid.removeWidget(self.title1)
        self.grid.addWidget(title2,1,5)
```

which I expect to change my "hello" to "bye" after I do this:

```
abutton.clicked.connect(self.myfunc)
```

but apparently that doesn't work. And I've checked: removeWidged works perfectly outside the function (my first thought was, maybe, i was doing something wrong in the function), and also the function does work itself(i checked it by making in print stuff and it did once I clicked the button, but the widget was still there)

what might I be doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: Is that typo title2=QtGui.QLalel('bye') in your code or only in this question ? (QLalel not QLabel)

Comment: it's only here sorry. i posted it as an example. UPD: edited the post

Comment: Have you confirmed that your callback is being called when you click the button ?

Comment: what does it mean? could you please give me an example, I'm not really good with PyQt, I first met it yesterday.

Comment: oh I just mean that if you add a print statement inside your myfunc function does it get printed or not ?

Comment: yes it does. the function seems to not work just with widgets. i thought maybe i give it a wrong name or forget/add extra 'self', but changing that and this didn't really help.

Comment: What happens if you use the setText() function on the QLabel ?

Answer (score 4):

You had typo and you trying local vars like so many issues in your code. Here is a working example

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class BASEGUICLS(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(BASEGUICLS, self).__init__(parent)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.title1=QtGui.QLabel('Hello')
        self.title2=QtGui.QLabel('bye')
        abutton=QtGui.QPushButton('Click me')
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.title1,1,5)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(abutton,3,5)
        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
        abutton.clicked.connect(self.myfunc)

    def myfunc(self):
        self.gridLayout.removeWidget(self.title1)
        self.title1.deleteLater()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.title2,1,5)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = BASEGUICLS(None)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I tried to run this one and it does something... but it just removes the widget without creating a new one. :(

Comment: What you mean by it does something ?. And it will create new one. You will see Hello will get deleted and Bye will be added in same place in grid layout. If I get correct that's what you asking for right ?

Comment: @Achayan Thanks for this hint it really helped me.